# Получить строку ресурсов в статическом контексте

Tags: java, android, android-resources

У фрагмента есть статический метод-фабрика `newInstance`. В нем в создается `Bundle` для дальнейшей передачи параметра `int`. Для метода `putInt()` и дальнешего извлечения хочу использовать строку - тег из ресурсов, но не получается получить при помощи метода  `Resources.getSystem().getString` как можно в данной ситуации получить строку из ресурсов? Поому что хранить статическое поле с тегом кажется нерациональным

Comment: В данном случае не нужна строка из ресурсов. Сделайте простую строковую константу. Строки из ресурсов обычно используются там, где их видит пользователь и они могут быть локализованы. Для названия экстра ресурсов это излишне.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

В данном конкретном случае, как раз использование ресурсов будет нерациональным. Достаточно объявить простую строковую константу и использовать её в качестсве тега:

```
public static final String TAG = "some_tag";
```

Если всё же хочется строка из ресурсов, то просто передайте `Resources` в ваш метод фабрику, вместе с остальными параметрами:

```
public static SomeFragment newInstance(Resources res, int id) {
    String tag = res.getString(R.string.some_id);
    ...
}
```

Answer (score 0):

А зачем `Resources.getSystem()`?

Там ведь нет ваших строк.

> Return a global shared Resources object that provides access to only system resources (no application resources)

Просто `Resources.getString(int id)` и все будет, если `id` верный.

**Дополнено**

Без доступа к `Context` к ресурсам приложения не добраться. Так что либо константа, что чаще всего и используется, либо `Context` как параметр `newInstance`.

Comment: Из статического контекста не получится вызвать Resources.getString(int id)